# Is there a way force a url to open up a specified file using .htacess

Tags: .htaccess

I don't know if this counts as a redirect, but I need all url's that start with a to open up the index.html in their first directory. *Meaning `website.com/blog`* and *`website.com/blog/3`* both use ***`website.com/explore/.index.html`*** file, while *`website.com/albums`*, *`website.com/albums/john-smith`*, and *`website.com/albums/john-smith/4`* all use ***`website.com/albulms/index.html`***

Is there anyway to make the `index.html` files load without changing the redirect of the `url` itself?

Comment: do you want to redirect in such ,website.com/albums to albums.html completely or just in uri and internally same path ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)

Comment: @MohammedElhag sorry. I meant to write website.com/albulms/index.html.

Comment: @MohammedElhag, also I wanted the url to remain website.com/albums while utilizing website.com/albulms/index.html. The same goes for website.com/albulms/john-smith, the url should still be what was type but reads from website.com/albulms/index.html. I saw something like this with 'ErrorDocument 404 /index.html' this doesn't change the url that was type but still loads index.html.